# How to recover files from Android device on bootloop?

Tags: data-recovery, boot-loop, linux

I have an old Android device that is stuck on bootloop. I found on [another website](https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/on-topic/android-phone-smashed-screen-data-recovery-from-phone-possible/) that you can use adb for this purpose.

I installed adb and found the device through `adb devices` command but when I try to run `adb shell` it says

```
adb shell error: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
```

What can I do? Thanks!

Comment: "device unauthorized" means you first have to accept a dialog that is shown on the phone. This only works if the device is fully booted and the UI is available. As you device does not boot I don't see a way you could enable adb if your phone is not rooted or bootloader unlocked.

Comment: @Robert Is there anyway at all to recover data ?

Comment: You can check online if your phone has something like a "safe mode" which reduces the boot sequence. If not I don't see a way to get access to the files if the phone is running Android 6+ (as newer versions should have encryption enabled by default).